# How to recognize repeated pattern over a data and make some recommendation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pattern-matching, bigdata, data-science

I have a huge dataset having some repeated data(user log file) and would like to to do similar pattern occurrence recognition and recommendation based on the user download. Once the pattern recognition is made, I need to recommend best possible value to the user.

For example following are the download logs based on time:

```
A C D F A C D A B D A C D F A C D A B D
```

I would like to recognize the pattern that exists between this dataset and display the result as:

```
A -> C = 4
C -> D = 4 
D -> F = 2
F -> A = 2
D -> A = 3
A -> B = 1
B -> D = 1
A -> C -> D = 2
C -> D -> F = 2 
D -> F -> A = 1
F -> A -> C = 1
C -> D -> A = 1
D -> A -> B = 1
A -> B -> D = 1
```

The number at the end represents the number of repetition  of that pattern.
When the user inputs "A", the best recommendation should be "C", And if the user input is "A -> C", then it should be "D".

Currently I am doing data cleaning using pandas in Python and for pattern recognition, I think scikit-learn might work (not sure though).
Is there any good library or algorithm that I can make a use for this problem or is there any good approach for this kind of problem ?

Since the data size is very big, I am implementing it using Python.

Comment: Why is A->C = 2, when there are 4 repititions of this pattern? Same for C->D?

Comment: @VivekKumar sorry my mistake. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Its not just these 2, all others have similar errors. `D->F`, `F->A`, `D->A`... Anyways, I get what you want. But you should post samples from your real data, not A, B, C.. (unless thats your real data)

Answer (score 0):

The current problem can be easily solved by `n_grams`. You can use [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to find out `n_grams` and their frequency in the text and generate the output you want.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Changed the token_pattern to identify only single letter words
# n_gram = (2,5), to identify from 2 upto 5-grams
cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,5), token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\b",
                     lowercase=False)

# Wrapped the data in a list, because CountVectorizer requires an iterable
data = ['A C D F A C D A B D A C D F A C D A B D']

# Learn about the data
cv.fit(data)

# This is just to prettify the printing
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(cv.get_feature_names(), columns = ['pattern'])

# Add the frequencies
df['count'] = cv.transform(data).toarray()[0]   #<== Changing to dense matrix

df

#Output

      pattern  count
          A B      2
        A B D      2
      A B D A      1
    A B D A C      1
          A C      4
        A C D      4
      A C D A      2
    A C D A B      2
      A C D F      2
    A C D F A      2
          B D      2
        B D A      1
      B D A C      1
    B D A C D      1
          C D      4
        C D A      2
      C D A B      2
    C D A B D      2
        C D F      2
      C D F A      2
    C D F A C      2
          D A      3
        D A B      2
      D A B D      2
    D A B D A      1
        D A C      1
      D A C D      1
    D A C D F      1
          D F      2
        D F A      2
      D F A C      2
    D F A C D      2
          F A      2
        F A C      2
      F A C D      2
    F A C D A      2
```

But I would recommend you to try recommender, pattern finding, association rule mining (apriori) algorithms etc. which will help you more.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to implement this.